# Scala reflection on object

Tags: scala

If I have the following scala object:

```
object CustomerState {
   val PENDING = "pending"
   val TRIAL = "trial"
   val PAYING = "paying"
   val DEACTIVATED_TRIAL = "deactivated_trial"
   val DEACTIVATED_PAYING = "deactivated_paying"
}
```

How can I obtain a list of all the val values?  In this case, I'm looking to get a List of ("pending", "trial", "paying", "deactivated_trial", "deactivated_paying")

Thanks in advance,
Todd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment I think the best you can do is to get a list of all zero-argument methods (since that's what `val`s are compiled to) and call them:

```
CustomerState.getClass.getMethods.toList.filter(_.getParameterTypes.isEmpty).map(_.invoke(CustomerState))
```

There is going to be a Scala-specific reflection library in 2.10, which will make things better.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you be using an [`Enumeration`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Enumeration.html)?

Example:

```
object Main extends Application {

   object CustomerState extends Enumeration {
     type CustomerState = Value
     val Pending, Trial, Paying, Deactivated = Value
   }

   import CustomerState._

   CustomerState.values foreach println // Will print each value
 }
```

Comment: I thought that the prevailing wisdom was that Scala enumeration was an aberration best avoided.

Comment: I am under same impression on use of enumeration in scala

Comment: I'll take enums over reflection any day of the week.

Comment: These objects are being used with Salat case classes, so it's not that simple